# How can I divide this jQuery data array?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following javascript array:

```
[{
    "id": "115",
    "poster": "809",
    "post": "alfa"
}, {
    "id": "127",
    "poster": "808",
    "post": "beta"
}]​
```

What do I need to do in order to extract the values into usable variables?

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
var arr = [{"id":"115","poster":"809","post":"alfa"},{"id":"127","poster":"808","post":"beta"}];
for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)<br/>
    document.write("id: " + arr[i].id + " poster: " + arr[i].poster + " post: " + arr[i].post + "<br/>");
```

Comment: @Adil: Thx for formatting my answer. I still don't know how to properly format a post :-)

Comment: You will learn with time, start experimenting with the options at the top of editor and learn for other answers formatting.

Answer (score 1):

What you have is an array with two elements

```
data = [a,b]
```

where both elements `a` and `b` are objects each having three fields (id,poster,post).

Recall that to access an element in the array at position `i` you simply write `data[i]` (this will access the `i`th element in your array i.e. one of the objects).

In order to access a field of the object `a` you simply use `a.fieldName`. For example `a.id` will access `id` field of object `a`. If you combine them both you can get `data[i].fieldName` to access field of specific object (for example `data[0].id` will return "115").

As a side note, array structures are iterable:

```
for(var i = 0;i<data.length;i++){
    id = data[i].id;
    post = data[i].post;
    poster = data[i].poster;

    document.write(id+" "+post+" "+poster+"<br/>");
}
```

**UPDATE**: Example on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/78Hfg/1/)

Comment: I saw a message which is "id: undefined poster: undefined post: undefined" where does it originate ?

Comment: @user1832879: I have updated my answer to provide you with a working example. Errors saying "undefined" mean that you are trying to access a field of an object (or otherwise) that does't exist within that object. Post the code that resulted in the error so that I can help you find the error :)